# How to use formData in OpenAPI with Swagger UI

Tags: openapi, swagger-ui

I'm using OpenAPI 3.0 and I need help defining a `multipart/form-data` request.

I have a `POST` request which needs to upload a binary file but I'm having trouble making it work in the Swagger UI

[image]

I tried different ways and the error appears:

```bash
Structural error at paths
should only have path names that start with `/`
Jump to line 22
Structural error at paths./v1/especialidades.post
should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: consumes, produces
Jump to line 24
Parser error 
bad indentation of a mapping entry
Jump to line 27
Structural error at paths./v1/especialidades.post.parameters.0
should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: type
Jump to line 34
Structural error at paths./v1/especialidades.post.parameters.0
should have either a `schema` or `content` property
Jump to line 34
Structural error at paths./v1/especialidades.post.parameters.0.in
should be equal to one of the allowed values
allowedValues: path, query, header, cookie
Jump to line 35
```

Comment: post your OpenAPI description so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a basic `multipart/form-data` OpenAPI description

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: test
  version: "1.0.0"
  description: a description of an api with a "multipart/form-data" request
servers:
  - url: 'https://api.host.com/v1'
    name: the host server
paths:
  "/image":
    post:
      description: a description of the api
      requestBody:
        description: a description of the requestBody
        required: true
        content:
          "multipart/form-data":
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                name:
                  type: string
                file:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
            encoding:
              name:
                headers:
                  content-disposition:
                    $ref: "#/components/headers/content-disposition"
                contentType: "application/json"
              file:
                headers:
                  content-disposition:
                    $ref: "#/components/headers/content-disposition"
                contentType: 'image/png, image/jpeg'
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            "application/json":
              schema:
                type: object
                properties: {}
components:
  headers:
    content-disposition:
      description: a description of this header
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
```

this works on app.swaggerhub.com
https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/jeremyfiel/test/1.0.0#/default/post_image

[image: old editor]

OR on the new editor

https://editor-next.swagger.io

[image: editor-next]

Comment: Which swagger ui are you using?  I tried it on https://editor-next.swagger.io and it works without any error